# Which OR for DocumentProperties' fMode

Tags: c++, windows

I have two doubt about theese two point of [DocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183576(v=vs.85).aspx) instruction on how to make local changes to printer settings:

> 4. Modify the appropriate members of the returned DEVMODE structure and **indicate which members were changed by setting the corresponding bits in the dmFields member** of the DEVMODE.

If I modify only one filed, i.e. `dmColor`, it's fine 'cause I set (assuming I have `PDEVMODEW settings`) `settings->dmFields = DM_COLOR`, but if I modify two fields (i.e. dmOrientation and dmColor), how can I specify both in dmField member?

> 5. Call DocumentProperties and pass the modified DEVMODE structure back as both the pDevModeInput and pDevModeOutput parameters and **specify both the DM_IN_BUFFER and DM_OUT_BUFFER values (which are combined using the OR operator)**.The DEVMODE structure returned by the third call to DocumentProperties can be used as an argument in a call to the CreateDC function.

Which OR operator should I use? Bitwise OR (`|`) or Logical OR (`||`)?

Comment: Bitwise or operator as you are trying to set the bit fields of the mask.

Comment: And how about the first question?

Comment: Same answer to both questions - they are bit-field-masks - you `|` in the corresponding bit mask for the fields you have changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude

Comment: Bitwise.  Use the predefined symbols to set the bits, DM_ORIENTATION | DM_COLOR.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx